# Mysql client NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, mysql, vert.x

All of a sudden I receive this message when I try to deploy my Vertx application:

> GRAVE: Unhandled exception java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>
> 'void io.vertx.sqlclient.impl.SocketConnectionBase.(io.vertx.core.impl.NetSocketInternal,
>   boolean, int, int, int, io.vertx.core.Context)'   at
>   io.vertx.mysqlclient.impl.MySQLSocketConnection.(MySQLSocketConnection.java:46)
>     at
>   io.vertx.mysqlclient.impl.MySQLConnectionFactory.lambda$connect$0(MySQLConnectionFactory.java:115)
>     at io.vertx.core.impl.FutureImpl.tryComplete(FutureImpl.java:131)

---

Here's the dependencies of my pom file:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-auth-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-milestone3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-mysql-client</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0-milestone3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web-templ-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

And this is the code that deploys the HTTP server and the database:

```
@Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> promise) throws Exception {
    // Deploy the database
    Promise<String> dbVerticleDeployment = Promise.promise();
    vertx.deployVerticle(new DatabaseVerticle(), dbVerticleDeployment);

    // When the database has been deployed, proceed with the server
    dbVerticleDeployment.future().compose(s -> {
      // Deploy the HTTPS server
      Promise<String> httpVerticleDeployment = Promise.promise();
      vertx.deployVerticle(new HttpsServerVerticle(), httpVerticleDeployment);

      // Return the future to notify the completion
      return httpVerticleDeployment.future();
    }).setHandler(stringAsyncResult -> {
      // Error handling
      if (stringAsyncResult.succeeded())
        promise.complete();
      else
        promise.fail(stringAsyncResult.cause());
    });

  }
```

I don't think that the error is on the code but it's something related to maven imports. I probably have messed up versions?

Here's the database

```
package com.rosanna.mkscoreboards.database;

import com.rosanna.mkscoreboards.database.service.DatabaseService;
import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLConnectOptions;
import io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool;
import io.vertx.serviceproxy.ServiceBinder;
import io.vertx.sqlclient.PoolOptions;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class DatabaseVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

  // Database connection constants
  private static final String HOST_NAME = "localhost";
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mkscoreboards";
  private static final String DB_USERNAME = "root";
  private static final String DB_PASSWORD = "temp_pass";
  private static final int MAX_POOL_SIZE = 20;

  // Queries
  private static HashMap<SqlQuery, String> queries = new HashMap<>();

  // Event but identifier
  public static final String MKSCOREBOARDS_QUEUE = "mkscoreboards.queue";

  @Override
  public void start(Promise<Void> promise) throws Exception {
    // Connection setup
    var connectOptions = new MySQLConnectOptions()
      .setPort(3306)
      .setHost(HOST_NAME)
      .setDatabase(DATABASE_NAME)
      .setUser(DB_USERNAME)
      .setPassword(DB_PASSWORD);

    var poolOptions = new PoolOptions().setMaxSize(MAX_POOL_SIZE);

    // Load the queries
    initQueries();

    // Create the pooled client
    var client = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions);
    DatabaseService.create(client, queries, ready -> {
      if (ready.succeeded()) {
        var binder = new ServiceBinder(vertx);
        binder.setAddress(MKSCOREBOARDS_QUEUE).register(DatabaseService.class, ready.result());
        promise.complete();
      } else {
        promise.fail(ready.cause());
      }
    });
  }

  private void initQueries() {
    if (queries.size() == 0) {

      queries.put(
        SqlQuery.LIST_AVAILABLE_GAMES,
        "SELECT * FROM games;"
      );

    }
  }

}
```

Here's the database service, taken from "Gentle guide to Vertx application"

```
@ProxyGen
@VertxGen
public interface DatabaseService {

  @GenIgnore
  static DatabaseService create(MySQLPool dbClient, HashMap<SqlQuery, String> sqlQueries, Handler<AsyncResult<DatabaseService>> readyHandler) {
    return new DatabaseServiceImpl(sqlQueries, dbClient, readyHandler);
  }

  @GenIgnore
  static DatabaseService createProxy(Vertx vertx, String address) {
    return new DatabaseServiceVertxEBProxy(vertx, address);
  }

  @Fluent
  DatabaseService listAllGames(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> resultHandler);
}
```

and

```
public class DatabaseServiceImpl implements DatabaseService {

  private final HashMap<SqlQuery, String> sqlQueries;

  private final MySQLPool client;

  public DatabaseServiceImpl(HashMap<SqlQuery, String> sqlQueries, MySQLPool client, Handler<AsyncResult<DatabaseService>> readyHandler) {
    this.sqlQueries = sqlQueries;
    this.client = client;

    client.getConnection(result -> {
      if (result.failed()) {
        readyHandler.handle(Future.failedFuture(result.cause()));
      } else {
        readyHandler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(this));
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public DatabaseService listAllGames(Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> resultHandler) {
    //TODO
    return null;
  }

}
```

Comment: If the same code was working before and you made changes in version (pom), you should look into code history and keep trying.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet from the database verticle? Would like to know how the mysql client is configured/used?

Comment: @tsegismont I have updated with more code

Comment: I can't see anything obviously wrong. Best course of action would be to share a small project on GitHub that reproduces the issue

Comment: @tsegismont https://github.com/buggiani-informatica/temp_vertx and you are ready to go. There are problems even if I copy the code from the official vertx guide about mysql reactive client, so it should be a bug! Can we move the discussion somewhere else?

Comment: @tsegismont bug found !! (https://prnt.sc/pz6n2f) check here, NetSocketInternal is in io.vertx.core.NET.impl.NetSocketInternal but you import it as io.vertx.core.impl.NetSocketInternal

Answer (score 0):

I have ended up with the fact that this error is related to a bug in vert.x; I have now this error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/vertx/core/impl/NetSocketInternal
>     at
>   io.vertx.mysqlclient.impl.MySQLConnectionFactory.lambda$connect$0(MySQLConnectionFactory.java:114)

And the pom is now the following (compare it with the pom in the question for comparing).

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-auth-jwt</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-mysql-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-web-templ-freemarker</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-service-proxy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
      <artifactId>vertx-codegen</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
      <version>${junit-jupiter.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

There must be issues with vertx itself because all versions are the same, I am using vertx 4

Answer (score 0):

```
use 

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.vertx/vertx-mysql-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-mysql-client</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

or the latest
```

Answer (score -1):

can you check that the various versions of the vertx components you are using are the same ?

Comment: If you look at the content of the pom you can see the version. I put 4.0.0-milestone3 but not everywhere, maybe I shoudl! I try now

Comment: Even if I put <version>4.0.0-milestone3</version> in every vertx component I still get that error! I might try a downgrade

Comment: bug found !! (https://prnt.sc/pz6n2f) check here, NetSocketInternal is in io.vertx.core.NET.impl.NetSocketInternal but you import it as io.vertx.core.impl.NetSocketInternal